# SSRS date drill through issue

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a matrix report called Store Sales which is made up of:

`STORES` in the row group 
`DATES` in the column group
`Sum of SALES` in the values group

The `DATES` column is formatted using the following expression:

`=format(Fields!DATES.Value, "MMM yyyy")`.

The `matrix` report also has 2 parameters `@Start` and `@End`. This all works great but I then added a linked report (Sales Store Details) so that the user can click on the SALES value for any purchase by month and store. The linked child report (Sales Store Details) uses the @Start and @End parameters from the original report (plus an additional @Store parameter) but this is where I run into problems. Rather than bringing me the purchase details for a particular store and month it brings me back everything from the time period selected from the original date parameters. So say I originally selected 2015-01-01 to 2015-06-30 with the @Start and @End parameters from the Store Sales report. When I then select on my FEB 15 value in my matrix report the drill down linked report doesnt just give me Feb 15 data but all the other months data too ie Jan-Jun 15. I understand that the original report parameters specified the Jan-Jun 15 date period but surely when I select on the Feb value in the matrix report that's what my linked report should drill down too right?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're passing the original `@Start` and `@End` parameters from the parent report. If so then you're passing the original date filtering parameters so it shouldn't be surprising that the date filtering on the child report is the same.

If you want to limit the child report's date filtering to only the month of the row being clicked you'll need to pass through the date value for that row instead of the original parameters. I'm not sure how your data set is structured but I assume there is some date column you use to determine the appropriate filtering to use.